# Marketing Cloud Ad Hoc Email Sends from CSV import

Tags: marketing-cloud

My client employs a number of agencies, some of which perform ad hoc sends using a CSV as the recipient list.

We are using the CRM ID as the subscriber Key, and don't want to cause inconsistencies in the All Subscribers table.

The CSV file contents could be either Leads or Contacts in Salesforce, or they may not be present.

I am attempting to craft the simplest and best solution given these conditions.

As I see it the solution could look like this:

1. Agency loads CSV to MC SFTP server.
2. MC performs import to a DE.
3. Automation then runs for each row in the table it will check if it exists as a Lead or Contact - if not, create new Lead.
4. How do we then send the email to these Leads and Contacts, making sure to use the CRM ID as the Subscriber key in the All Subscribers table? If we send to the DE then I believe any new records would be loaded to the All Subscribers table with a different Subscriber Key (whatever is set on the DE as relating to the Subscriber Key). Ideas: add the leads and contacts to a Salesforce Campaign (via Ampscript automation) and send via Salesforce.

I feel like there may be a simpler solution though?